# Remove unnecessary li

Tags: php, html

`echo $nav` gives code like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="someclass">sometext
        <ul>
            <li class="someclass">sometext</li>
            <li class="spacer"></li>
            <li class="someclass">sometext</li>
            <li class="spacer"></li>
            <li class="someclass">sometext</li>
            <li class="spacer"></li>
            <li class="someclass">sometext</li>
            <li class="spacer"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="spacer"></li>
    <li class="someclass">sometext</li>
    <li class="spacer"></li>
</ul>
```

There are list items with class `spacer` inside each child `ul`, after each normal list item.
How do I remove the `spacer` list items which are grandchildren of the main list, using PHP?
*Example:* `<ul> <li> <ul> <li class="spacer">`

---

**I'm searching for a regular expression, which should erase `<li class="spacer"></li>` only in a child `<ul>` element.**

Comment: Where is that `<li class="spacer"></li>` coming from?

Comment: Edit the code that creates `$nav`? There isn't enough info to go on here...

Comment: am I missing something? have you tried backspace?

Comment: Don't remove them, just don't add them.

Comment: Judging from his question, he's saying that echoing $nav results in the output above.  So str_replace on $nav should do it.

Comment: it comes from the deep php source of the cms

Comment: Using your mouse place the text cursor after `<li class="spacer"></li>`. Now, careful not to go overboard (remember to create backups before deleting anything!) press the backspace key until the line has completely disappeared. Repeat for each other line. N.B. These skills are transferrable to other such situations as you come across them.

Comment: what do you mean remove? can you post the $nav and its value so we can better evaluate your question.

Comment: Why do you need to remove them ? you mean instead `<br />`?

Comment: str_replace can't do this work. Because only ul-child li-child.spacer should be removed. Li with class "spacer" inside general ul should exist.

Comment: This question is silly. The solution isn't 'fixed' by masking the base of the problem, which is where the extra spacers originate. Remove them from where they first enter the code.

Comment: @Thomas Clayson haha, thanks for the joke =) I can't edit the code, because it comes from the source of the cms. I shouldn't edit general php source, because it's used in much places.

Comment: @ParPar you can't have line breaks within `ul` elements. They need to be within an `li` to be valid, and furthermore, you shouldn't be using linebreaks or 'special' lis to format the layout.

Comment: @Steve I get you. I use wordpress and its like this a lot. You have to get rid of things on the fly, you can't edit the source. Can you hide them with Javascript?

Comment: I want to remove them, because display:inline-block is used in this menu with justify alignment. So the after each li there is a whitespace, which causes bugs in IE7.

Comment: How about using JavaScript to remove them client-side?

Comment: Or css: `ul li ul li.spacer { display: none; }`

Comment: @Steve You'd be doing the code a huge favor by fixing it the right way.

Comment: @Thomas Clayson want to do it by php, so the jump-effect on javascript load would not exist.

Comment: @MetalFrog its probably not possible. I don't know what CMS he's using, but I know from using Wordpress that its not always possible to delete from the source. Things like the admin menu in Wordpress are built into the core wordpress files. If you edit them then plugins may not work, and on upgrading the code base it will be overwritten.

Comment: @Thomas Clayson this doesnt work, because after each <li> there is nbsp;, which causes bug. The only way I see to remove <li class="spacer"> inside child ul and remove the whitespace inside this ul

Comment: @ThomasClayson Then I'd push for a change to WordPress, so it could be adopted and repaired properly. Complacency isn't really an excuse to let it keep happening, neither is "it'll break things cobjobbed together on top of something that shouldn't be happening in the first place." http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ Anyhow, this is turning into a discussion,s o I'll stop so we don't clutter up the page.

Comment: @MetalFrog ok, wordpress is used. Function generates li.spacer after each li. But, li.spacer should exist only in general ul, not the child. Child is used for dropdown.

Comment: Searching for a right regex, which should erase <li class="spacer"></li> only in child <ul>

Comment: @Steve So throw a new menu generator into your theme functions file and use that instead. Now you have full control over how your menu is built and displayed, and it won't be overwritten by core system updates.

Comment: @MetalFrog you are talking about menu walker? I don't know how to use it and not sure can it help or not

Comment: @steve look for where $nav is being built. Is it http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu ? Check what's being passed as arguments.

Comment: @Steve - if you're using wordpress you should create your own menus. :) forget the built in menu creator. There's usually not many times you will need a dynamic menu. If you DO need a dynamic menu then there are ways to search for pages and child pages and such using WP_Query and build your own menu dynamically. You could even copy the `wp_nav_menu` function from MetalFrog's comment and use that as a starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about `str_replace`?

```
    $nav = str_replace('<li class="spacer"></li>','',$nav);
```

`edited code below`

Based on the new requirement this code works.  I know its hacky and sloppy but it works:

```
    $temp = explode("\n",$nav);

    for ($i=0;$i<count($temp);$i++) {

            if (strstr($temp[$i],"<ul>")) {
                    $nested_ul = 1;
            }

            if (strstr($temp[$i],"</ul>")) {
                    $nested_ul = 0;
            }

            if ($nested_ul==0) {
                    if (!strstr($temp[$i],"spacer")) {

                            $new_nav .= $temp[$i]."\n";
                    }
            } else {
                    $new_nav .= $temp[$i]."\n";
            }
    }


    echo $new_nav;
```

Comment: seems the fastest way to use regex, any solution? I'm not pro in regexp

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to the `$nav` variable to remove it (which you likely do) then I'd just use CSS to hide it, something like this should work:

```
li ul li.spacer {
  display:none;
}
```

If however you have access to `$nav` - delete that spacer li from the code. Simples.

Also, on a side note. having empty elements like that on the page as "spacers" is semantically bad. This should be handled via CSS, add margins/padding on other elements on the page, don't use a class of spacer, if you do then you may as well go back to using stray `<br />` tags everywhere to create spaces.

Comment: after each li there is nbsp; in code. So the display:none doesnt fix whitespace bug in ie7

Comment: these <li class="spacer"></li> should be erased inside child ul

Answer (score 1):

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($nav);
$spacers = $xml->xpath('li//li[@class="spacer"]');
foreach($spacers as $i => $n) {
  unset($spacers[$i][0]);
}
echo $xml->asXML();
```

This is converting to XML (use a recent PHP 5.3 version and DOMDocument to export to HTML). Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ul>
    <li class="someclass">sometext
        <ul>
            <li class="someclass">sometext</li>

            <li class="someclass">sometext</li>

            <li class="someclass">sometext</li>

            <li class="someclass">sometext</li>

        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="spacer"/>
    <li class="someclass">sometext</li>
    <li class="spacer"/>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

"Easily" is relative.  It depends on a few things.  If you want, modify where the `$nav` is getting generated from.

Comment: I can't directly edit code which generates it. So the way is to use pre_replace, searchin for the right regex

Comment: @steve You've said that you can't a few times, but I don't think I've seen an explanation as to *why* you cannot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$nav = str_replace('<li class="spacer"></li>', '', $nav);
```

Answer (score 0):

use preg_replace to replace the li tags:

```
$new_nav = preg_replace('/<li class="spacer"></li>/', '', $nav);
echo $nav;
```

Comment: only ul-child li-child.spacer should be removed. Li with class "spacer" inside general ul should exist

Comment: this code removes all the spacer li, should work JUST for the child ul

Comment: Seeing your extra requirement you added in the question, I would say the easiest way would be to use JS and not try this with PHP

Comment: js will cause jump-effect, when its loaded

Comment: so the page will be opened with bug, then it will be fixed with js, when it will be loaded - "jump effect". Its not good

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways:

1. Do not create it. It will be easier if you do not create something you do not want. It will be easier to maintain. So if you have any control over what is generated into `$var` string, just change it.
2. Simply replace it like that: `str_replace('<li class="spacer"></li>', $var)`.
3. Use some HTML parser and remove the nodes.
4. Use JavaScript to remove `<li class="spacer"></li>` on client side.

Answer (score 0):

Use `substr_replace` and `strpos` instead of `str_replace`, and specify an offset just after the first spacer.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Answer (score 0):

Add the following CSS

```
ul ul li.spacer { display: none; }
```